# HTML Kickstart light box class on <a>

Tags: javascript, lightbox, innerhtml, html5-kickstart

I am having a bit of a problem with getting a link to show in a lightbox.

I'm using HTML Kickstart which uses fancybox (I think). When I click on a button the below function is called. It does change the innerHTML but for some reason the `id='inline'` is ignored.

I copied and pasted the HTML code 
`<a id='inline' href='http://sample.mylink.com'>New Link</a>` 
to my webpage and it works as expected. When I click the button the the link opens in a lightbox.

Anyone know why the id is being ignored when I do this via javascript?

**EDIT**

**Javascript**

```
function loadGoGo() 
{
    alert('Boo!');
    var link = document.getElementById("GoGo");
    link.innerHTML = "<table class='sortable'>" +
                    "<tr>" +
                        "<td>" +
                            "<a id='inline' href='reply.html'>Boo Link</a>" +
                        "</td>" +
                    "</tr>" +
                "</table>";
}
```

**HTML**

```
<Button onClick="loadGoGo()" >Load Go Go Link</Button>
<div id="GoGo">
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('a#inline').fancybox({
        overlayOpacity: 0.2,
        overlayColor: '#000'
    });
```

This is the actual code I'm using, the css is whatever fancybox uses. I would have thought this would work with an id selector.

Comment: can you provide css class description here?

Comment: Open console if there is any exceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I don't know what the problem is but I found a work around.

I simply call a javascript function when the link is clicked, which in turn calls some jQuery.

**Javascript function to load innerHTML**

```
function loadGoGo() 
{
    alert('Boo!');
    var link = document.getElementById("GoGo");
    link.innerHTML = "<table class='sortable'>" +
                    "<tr>" +
                        "<td>" +
                            "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick='javascript:showPopup();'>Boo Link</a>" +
                        "</td>" +
                    "</tr>" +
                "</table>";
}
```

**HTML**

```
<Button onClick="loadGoGo()" >Load Go Go Link</Button>
<div id="GoGo">
</div>
```

**Extra Javascript function to open anchor in lightbox**

```
function showPopup()
{
    $.fancybox({
        href            : 'reply.html',
        overlayOpacity  : 0.2,
        overlayColor    : '#000'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well probably your css class has additional selector, it could be

```
.parentClass .lightbox { /**css here*/}
```

As i mentioned above problem is in css selector. [More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors) read Information: Selectors based on relationships part. 
I am not sure about how light box works but try to set class on parent element of A lets say to td then selector

```
.lightbox a {styles here}
```

will work thats mean that that style will be applied to all elements inside of element with class lightbox

Comment: Hey man, I updated my question. I tried to get around the whole issue by using an id selector but I'm still getting the same problem. Should this without changing the css?